# Django - S3 - SQS Delivery Instead of Retrieving

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I'm currently using Django with S3. When a new object is created a notification is sent through SQS.[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) I'm receiving the notification by using boto3. [Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message).I can receive messages using the receive_message function, but I have to run the function every minute to see if new messages are available. Is there a way of getting the messages delivered automatically to my django app instead of having to retrieve them by continuously running a function every minute to see if there are new messages?  Delivered instead of retrieved.

Comment: What do you mean by `delivering automatically to django app`?

Comment: Is there a way to receive the message without pinging the SQS server every minute to see if there's a message? Can I do something so that I can receive without actively trying to retrieve every minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive notifications in django app you will probably need api endpoint to receive http notifications - django View (with authentication).

Sending notification as HTTP POST requests to your api from AWS may be done in several ways:

- with [AWS SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html#SendMessageToHttp.subscribe) - create topic, subscribe your app, publish messages from S3 / SQS
- with [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) - adding simple lambda function to make http post to your api (i.e. with js and axios)

S3 can route notifications via both of them, or you can use them with AWS SQS for additional processing logic.

Other less preferred polling options include using [Celery with SQS as broker](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html) but this will most probably require separate worker just for this broker and this is also periodic polling. Or most dirty way - querying S3 api to get full object list and detect new / modified.

Comment: Those AWS services would be the way to go since they can be event-driven from S3. It's important to consider what happens if the app misses the push/POST event and if you need to handle that gracefully -- a tradeoff vs. the polling SQS approach